# Post case link in Chatter

Tags: visual-workflow

The Chatter posts include the particular Salesforce record that they are referencing, however the record isn’t linked within the text. For example:

Currently a Flow-posted Chatter message might read:

“Hi, Record 00Q8e00000160c7EAA needs updating, please update the Title field. Thanks.”

We’d like the Chatter post to read:

“Hi, Record 00Q8e00000160c7EAA needs updating, please update the Title field. Thanks.”

See how the record is “clickable” so the user doesn’t have to copy and paste the ID into their browser URL bar?

Do you know how to configure this linked text for an automated Chatter post within a Flow?

Answer (score 0):

For the message part of the 'Post to Chatter' Action in your Flow, create a formula and use something like this:

```
"Hi, " & "<https://YourOrgHere.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/RecordNameHere/"+{!$Record.Id}+"/view|"+"Record"+{!$Record.Id}+">" & " needs updating. Please update the Title field. Thanks."
```

Please be sure to swap out 'YourOrgHere' in the example with whatever comes before lightning.force in your URL and 'RecordNameHere' with the record type you're trying to link to.

If this works for you, please mark this as the best answer. Thank you!

Here is a resource link to a helpful blog on this topic: [Post to Chatter with hyperlinks to records](http://smukov.github.io/blog/2018/08/11/Post-to-Chatter-from-Process-Builder-with-hyperlinks-to-records/#:%7E:text=In%20Summer%20%2718%20Release%20Salesforce,as%20Process%20Builder%20or%20Flow.)

Comment: How to generate the links when the flows gets record from automation and post it to chatter, Rather than we give the record id and all details

Comment: @Aswin - I'm not sure I understand the question.  When you're creating the flow automation, you will need to create a resource within the flow.  The resource should be a formula, similar to the one I outlined above.  When you choose the messagee that posts to the chatter, you'll set the message body equal to the formula resource, and it should create the text with a working link, as requested.

Comment: Hi there, Opportunity " & "<https://00D58000000I0NG.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/0128e000000CgLPAA0/"+{!$Record.Id}+"/view|"+"Record"+{!$Record.Id}+">" & " with Channel Partner Site: {!$Record.Account.Name} by RSM: {!$Record.Owner.FirstName} {!$Record.Owner.LastName} was created and needs a Case for its installation.

Comment: is this is the correct formula

Comment: Hi there, Opportunity " & "<https://00D58000000I0NG.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/0128e000000CgLPAA0/"+{!$Record.Id}+"/view|"+"Record"+{!$Record.Id}+">" & " with Channel Partner Site: {!$Record.Account.Name} by RSM: {!$Record.Owner.FirstName} {!$Record.Owner.LastName} was created and needs a Case for its installation.

Comment: Based on the provided info it should be: "Hi there, Opportunity " & "<https://00D58000000I0NG.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/RecordNameHere/"+{!$Record.Id}+"/view|"+"Record"+{!$Record.Id}+">" & " with Channel Partner Site: " +  {!$Record.Account.Name} + " by RSM: " + {!$Record.Owner.FirstName} + " "+{!$Record.Owner.LastName}+ " was created and needs a Case for its installation."

Comment: Be sure to update RecordNameHere in the URL with the object you're trying to reference. I have updated the answer post with more info / Links to reference material for you.